# CreateEnhMetaFile and PlayEnhMetaFile result in blank EMF document

Tags: c++, gdi, emf

I am trying to replay an existing EMF file into another one and change some of the records. For starters i wanted to replay the whole document into another one but the resulting document is blank and the resolution is much smaller then the original.

```
HENHMETAFILE hEmf = GetEnhMetaFile(_T("test.emf"));

ENHMETAHEADER emfHeader;
GetEnhMetaFileHeader(hEmf, 256, &emfHeader);

RECT rcFrame;
memcpy(&rcFrame, &emfHeader.rclFrame, sizeof(RECT));

HDC compressedEmf = CreateEnhMetaFile(NULL, _T("compressed.emf"), &rcFrame, NULL);
PlayEnhMetaFile(compressedEmf, hEmf, &rcFrame);


HENHMETAFILE tmpEMF =  CloseEnhMetaFile(compressedEmf);
DeleteEnhMetaFile(tmpEMF);
```

Comment: I assume you have proper error checking in the real program?

Comment: Sure, and the return values are all as expected so it seems to work but doesn't result in a copy of the original EMF document.

Answer (score 1):

```
GetEnhMetaFileHeader(hEmf, 256, &emfHeader);
```

Your above line seems to be creating the problem.Here you have assumed that your *headersize* is 256 bye which may not be true. The correct way to find it out is:

```
int  length = GetEnhMetaFileHeader(hEMf,0,NULL);
GetEnhMetaFileHeader(hEmf, length, &emfHeader);
```

OR

```
GetEnhMetaFileHeader(hEmf, sizeof(ENHMETAHEADER), &emfHeader);
```

You may want to refer the following link which describes this concept in detailed way.

http://aranna.altervista.org/data/ch18c.html